# Strange border around R heatmap

Tags: r, border, heatmap

This is my code:
data_subset <- df[, c("pSent", "pReturned", "age")]

correlation_matrix <- cor(data_subset, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

pheatmap(correlation_matrix, color = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(100), display_numbers = T, number_color = "white", fontsize_number = 10, annotation_colors = list(numbers = list(fontfamily = "Arial")), border_color = "white")

When the heatmap is created it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2fNx.png)

How to remove the borders?

border_color = NA or border = NA worked not as expected

Comment: The 'strange borders' you are seeing appear to be the cluster annotations. Add the arguments `cluster_rows = FALSE` and `cluster_cols = FALSE` if you don't want them.